# QGIS (3.28.2-Firenze) QGZ save error - "Unable to perform zip"

Tags: error, save, qgs, qgz

QGIS (3.28.2-Firenze) QGZ save error gives the message: "Unable to perform zip"
This occurs when trying to save, or save as. Folder location does not matter either.

Trying to save the project as a QGS gives this error:

> Unable to save attachments archive

It does, however, actually save a QGS file, as well as a qgs~ file.

This is a project that has been saved numerous times over the past 5 or 6 months, with no issues. The last save date was two days prior (thought it was saved yesterday, but apparently not by the datestamp)

OS is OSX 10.14.6 Mojave (Mac)

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution that worked to fix the problem and allow new QGZ saves.

Open a new instance of QGIS under a different profile, then open the newly saved QGS file. It opened properly, with no apparent issues and all new updates saved correctly. Then save as QGZ worked correctly. Testing on the old instance still was not saving properly, but the new instance under the new profile was working correctly. Shut down QGIS completely, re-opened and tested under both profiles, both functioning correctly when saving projects.